# Как отследить поведение мыши через элементы Windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здраствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста какой должен получиться код и какие элементы и события/свойства надо выбрать? Выполняется в WinForms.
Разработать приложение, в котором в текстовом поле будет
описываться поведение мыши. При нажатии левой, правой и средней
кнопки мыши появляются следующие тексты: Нажата левая кнопка;
Нажата правая кнопка; Нажата средняя кнопка. При опускании любой
кнопки текст стирается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать это для определённого элемента - пишите `{Элемент. , если форма - ничего не пишите}{MouseDown/другие предложенные варианты} += {название метода}`
Примеры:

```
public void Controls_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        ((Control)sender).Capture = false;
        var m = Message.Create(Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(0x2), IntPtr.Zero);
        WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MouseDown += Controls_MouseDown;
    panel1.Click += Controls_MouseDown;
    pictureBox1.MouseDown += Controls_MouseDown;
}
```

Comment: У вас что-то не то с форматированием кода. `Form1_Load` внутри `Controls_MouseDown`

Comment: Ой) Да.. жаль что я увидел только сейчас